# Coq makefile "Top." Prefix

Tags: coqide

I am using the automatic Coq 8.5 makefile generator. This makefile prefixes all modules by "Top." .
Now let's say you run a lot of files by make and then want to change/debug some file in the IDE.
Then the annoying fact is that Coq complains it cannot find the compiled other files, because in the IDE  it assumes the names without the "Top" prefix.
I tried to tweak the makefile to get rid of this prefix. But I always ended in some error message of the make. 
Can someone show me either how to remove "Top" prefix in make or tell the IDE to use the "Top" prefix.

Answer (score 3):

You can start CoqIDE with the following arguments `coqide -R . Top`.

This will get rid of the following error `Error: The file ..../Logic.vo contains library Top.Logic and not library Logic`.

Answer (score 1):

This is annoying indeed. In order to avoid that kind of annoyance, always start your `_CoqProject` with a line listing options:

```
-Q . MyProject
```

To note: the options you can put on the first line of your `_CoqProject` are the ones listed when calling `coqtop -help`.