# Require module in same directory

Tags: coq

I don't know what's the recommended approach to manage large projects and load paths, but I usually work on a single directory where I have different files which should be able to work together. What I usually do is compile, say, `A.v` from the command line with `coqc A.v`. Then, in `B.v`, which is in the same directory, I'd like to `Require A` and try some things interactively in CoqIDE or some other IDE (I often use a plugin for vscode). The problem is that I have to explicitly add the current directory to the load to make it work: `Add LoadPath "/absolute/path/to/my/project". Require A.`. Is there a simpler way to do it? At least I'd like to be able to do write relative paths in `Add LoadPath` so I don't have to change every file when I rename my directory.

Comment: Perhaps [Manage your Coq projects like a pro](https://blog.zhenzhang.me/2016/09/19/coq-dev.html) blog post can help. It might be a bit outdated, since Coq's build system was upgraded last year. You might want to read the corresponding reference manual chapter and copy Makefile from it.

Comment: I don't understand your question, because for me (under linux), I do exactly what you would like to do and never have to use the `Add LoadPath` command.

Comment: See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202666/coqide-cant-load-modules-from-same-folder), though I am not fully satisfied with the proposed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started I would recommend to setup your Coq project using a `_CoqProject` file.
Imagine your coq project where called `project`. Then to add files `A.v` and `B.v` you would put the following into your `_CoqProject` file:

```
-R . project
./A.v
./B.v
```

This way you can use the Coq makefile generator to get all you need:

`coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile`

Both emacs ProofGeneral and CoqIDE should then be able to load your files using only `Require Import A.`. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138770/coq-makefile-top-prefix), it can be the case that CoqIDE will complain about library `project.A` being in file `A.v` and not library `A`. This can be fixed by starting `coqide -R . project`.

As suggested in the comments I would recommend to read the manual part about Coq project files and [makefiles](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/tools.html#Makefile) if you want to really understand how to use this machinery.